# Call Axes from another GUI

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I have created two GUI .
In one GUI i have axes1 and in another GUI i have function which blur image using slider.

GUI1
[image]

GUI2
[image: GUI2]

this is the function in GUI2.

```
function gui_blurSlider_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% 
% 
% here global var img is a image used in GUI1 

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider
global var img slideval;
slideval=get(hObject,'Value');
fs = fspecial('gaussian', [3,3], slideval);
gblur = imfilter(img,fs,'replicate');

axes(handles.axes1);                   %error executing this line

imshow(gblur);
```

Comment: Do you really need another GUI for the slider or you could simply put it below the axes in GUI1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error likely occurs because this command:

```
axes(handles.axes1)
```

refers to an element of GUI 1 whereas the line is executed in GUI 2 and the latter does not recognize the variables coming from GUI 1 because they have their own workspace.

You could work around this problem using `setappdata/getappdata` or else to share data between the 2 GUIs. For example, in the GUI 1 `Opening_Fcn` you could write something like this:

```
setappdata(0,'hAxes1',handles.axes1)
```

to store `handles.axes1` in the root and make it 'visible'  from within GUI 2. Then in GUI 2, retrieve the variable named `hAxes1`, which is actually `handles.axes1` from GUI 1:

```
function gui_blurSlider_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% 
% 
% here global var img is a image used in GUI1 

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider

%// NEW ==========================
    Axes1InGUI2 = getappdata(0,'hAxes1');
%// NEW ==========================

global var img slideval;
slideval=get(hObject,'Value');
fs = fspecial('gaussian', [3,3], slideval);
gblur = imfilter(img,fs,'replicate');

axes(Axes1InGUI2);  %// Change here

imshow(gblur); %// Or skip previous line and simply use imshow(gblur,'Parent',Axes1InGUI2)
```

Previous answer:

Here is a solution in which the slider is actually in GUI 1 right below the axes 1, so you save yourself the trouble of sharing the data between 2 GUIs. That's a programmatic GUI but the principle is similar with a GUIDE-made GUI. If yu really need to use another GUI for the task please ask.

Here is the commented code:

```
function GaussianSlider()
clear
clc
close all

%// Test image
handles.Image = imread('peppers.png');

%// Create GUI components
hFig = figure('Position',[500 500 500 500],'Units','pixels');

handles.axes1 = axes('Units','pixels','Position',[50 80 400 400]);
handles.slider = uicontrol('Style','slider','Position',[50 30 400 20],'Min',3,'Max',15,'Value',3);%// I commented this for the purpose of demonstration. 'Callback',@gaussian_blur(handles));

handles.Text1 = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[80 70 70 20],'String','Slider Value');
handles.SValue = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[160 70 70 20],'String','0');

%// Used to continously display the image as it's being changed
handles.Listener = addlistener(handles.slider,'Value','PostSet',@(s,e) gaussian_blur(handles));

%// The 'Parent' property is useful here.
imshow(handles.Image,'Parent',handles.axes1);

%// Update guidata.
guidata(hFig);

    %// Slider's listener object callback
    function gaussian_blur(handles)

        %// Get the slider's value
        slideval = round(get(handles.slider,'Value'));


        fs = fspecial('gaussian',slideval,slideval);

        handles.Image= imfilter(handles.Image,fs,'conv');

        %// Update text box
        set(handles.SValue,'String',num2str(slideval));

        imshow(handles.Image,'Parent',handles.axes1);

        guidata(hFig);

    end
end
```

When the slider is at 0:

[image]

And after sliding it:

[image]

Comment: i need to use another gui.

what should i write instead of this line.
axes(handles.axes1);